Searching for a fanfic in which Gaunt inheritance rejects Harry for not being pure
So I'm searching for a fanfic that has family inheritances. Harry was trying to inherit the Slytherin magic, even though the gaunt magic totally rejected him for not being pure. But he's been in the Chamber, and though he didn't get the Slytherin magic at the usual time, there have been hints that it wants? to be inherited by him?
And I may be mixing it with another fic, but Pureblood heirs are never photographed before their thirteenth birthday because families don't want it known which inheritances worked or didn't. (Because their features may change)
And it MIGHT be a time travel fic, because since Harry originally didn't know about this he couldn't inherit anything?
Additional details:
Hello, I'm looking for a fic in which I'm not sure about this detail: At Gringotts, when Harry is thirteen, he checks his inheritances. More sure of this part: He gets some, but the Gaunt magic/family/inheritances totally rejects him. He's not pure. There's a whisper on the wind, a faint something Slytherin that is approving, however. (There's no Slytherin magic/family/inheritance). Later on, Harry is in the CoS, and again, there is a faint impression of something Slytherin being approving. The fic is ongoing, and as of yet, there's no actual Slytherin inheritance.

I found it! It's in another life by drifting_melody.

The Judging required both blood and an emotional, intellectual connection to one’s past, after all, which was why she’d never undergone it in her first life. She’d known nothing of her history, and the social taboo around discussing it outside the family meant she’d never learned until it was too late.


The Gaunt magicks had taken one look at her half-blood status and rejected her. Half-muggle, they’d snarled. Half-mud.
(there had been something else as well – a faint caress, barely more than a breath, of pride)

